# How to specify notification between threads if they don't have common data in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread in Java which starts a `HttpService`.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProceeBuilder(command);
Process process = pb.start();
process.waitFor();
```

I have another thread which checks if the service is started.

```
while (result != 0) {
  ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocker(port);
  socket.close();
  result = 0
  catch (BindException be) {
    result = 1;
  }
}
```

Now I need to somehow get information about whether the service has failed to start or it's successfully started. I need to get this back to the Main class which started both of these threads in order to proceed. Something like

```
while (!started || !failed) {
     wait for getting information from the threads.
}
```

What can you advise?
Thank you.

Comment: why do you need a second thread to check if the service is started? can you not just wait for startup in the main thread? ie, start the http service then call something like waitFor(serverStarted())? see http://tempus-fugit.googlecode.com/svn/site/documentation/time.html#Condition e.g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a callback that you pass to both threads?

(omitted try-catches)

```
public class MyCallback {
  private Boolean processSuccess;
  private Boolean serviceSuccess;
  public synchronized void notifyProcessStart(boolean success) {
    this.processSuccess = success;
    this.notifyAll();
  }
  public synchronized void notifyServiceCheck(boolean success) {
    this.serviceSuccess = success;
    this.notifyAll();
  }
  public synchronized void waitForResult() {
    while(processSuccess == null || serviceSuccess == null) {
      this.wait();
    }
    // ... do something good
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry but I am afraid that your code that checks that service is started has bug. 
This code is running very quickly, starts server socket and immediately closes it. If you mean that this thread should exit when process is started listening to the same port it is wrong. Your process has 50% of chance to start successfully and other 50% to fail because when it is trying to start listening to the port your watch dog is listening to the same port itself.

So, I believe that you should try to run process using ProcessBulder (exactly as you are doing) and then start delayed watchdog task that tries to **connect** to this port, i.e.

```
private boolean isServiceRunning() {
    int port = 123;
    try {
        new Socket("localhost", port).close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This method should be called from separate thread. The best way to implement thread is to use some tool that does it for you. In this case java.util.Timer is the best choice. I am suggesting to run periodic task that will call our method isServiceRunning() and cancel itself if result is true:

```
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(isServiceRunning()) {
                this.cancel();
            }
        }

    }, new Date(), 10000);
```

But if this solution is not good for you I'd suggest you to implement interthread communication using wait() and notfify(). Do not forget that both must be in synchronized block.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using boolean flags. Adapting your example code:

Thread 1:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command); 
Process process = pb.start();
process.waitFor();
if(!wasConnectionEstablished()) {
     setConnectionFailed(true);
}
```

Thread 2:

```
while ((result != 0) && (!isConnectionFailed())) {        
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocker(port);        
    socket.close();        
    result = 0        
    catch (BindException be) {        
        result = 1;
        wait(timeout);
    }
}
if(isConnectionFailed()) 
   throw new ConnectionFailedException();
else setConnectionEstablished(true);
//continue normal execution
```

Comment: I edited out that part. After thinking about it more, my spiel about processes wasn’t as relevant as I initially thought. IPC is inter-process communication.